# Controlling the stream of an audio / video streaming server

Tags: windows, driver

I've searched high and low for an answer to this and in desperation, I'm now starting to ask questions on these types of forums for anyone who can give me some insight!

I'm looking at being able to control the audio and / or video stream from an open source streaming server. I'm looking at packages like Icecast, Darwin and OggVorbis. I would even consider something like VLC if it's practical enough.

What I'm trying to achieve is - if a number of clients are listening (via Internet Explorer) on particular channel / port combination to a particular audio or video file, I want to be able to (as an administrator of said streaming server) pause / rewind / fast forward the audio or video file that they're listening to and then continue playing the file for the clients.  Ultimately it'll be a simple, analogue USB device that will manage those controls (of which I'll simply build a device driver that'll be able to use some sort of API that I'll also build for the streaming server), but for the time being I'd just like to find a way of having that level of control from a command line.

Does anyone have any insight as to how that can be achieved?

Initially I was looking at using something like JWPlayer to be the IE based audio (in this case) client as it has an API that can be written to and then control the play / pause / rewind / fast forward through that API. However, I'm unable to register events from the USB device to control events within IE. From discussions with others, it's possible to bring this level of functionality through a user mode application, only really possible with Chrome, however, I'm  restricted in **having** to use IE as the clients browser.

Therefore, I wondered if there could be a different approach in controlling the server's stream to those clients, hence my question (and my frustration!)

Thoughts / comments or questions!?